Pandas merge without copying the data
I have a dataframe (df1) with unique IDs (col1) but also duplicated IDs for each row (col2). On another dataframe (df2) I have unique IDs of col2. I want to somehow link the two dataframes together without copying the data of df2 (col3) (linking instead of copying).
Here is an simplified example of what I try to achieve :
df1 = pd.read_clipboard()
    col1    col2
0   a   A
1   b   A
2   c   B
3   d   C
4   e   B

df2 = pd.read_clipboard()
    col2    col3
0   A   Albert is the best
1   B   Bernard is cool
2   C   Conrad is ok

df3 # col3 being the values of df2, not copied
    col1    col2    col3
0   a   A   Albert is the best
1   b   A   Albert is the best
2   c   B   Bernard is cool
3   d   C   Conrad is ok
4   e   B   Bernard is cool

I've been using pd.merge and it creates the df3 I want but uses too much memory, I think that it copies the values to the new tables but it's useless as values are only in a few states.
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col2', how='left')

There is a copy=False attribute I can add but doesn't change anything, it stills seems to copy the data.

I would suggest to convert the non-key columns to Categorical, which should save a lot of memory if you have many duplicates:
out = pd.merge(df1.astype({'col1': 'category'}),
               df2.astype({'col3': 'category'}),
               on='col2', how='left')

Or, for simplicity:
out = pd.merge(df1.astype('category'),
               df2.astype('category'),
               on='col2', how='left')

But col2 won't be kept as a categorical.
Output:
  col1 col2                col3
0    a    A  Albert is the best
1    b    A  Albert is the best
2    c    B     Bernard is cool
3    d    C        Conrad is ok
4    e    B     Bernard is cool

If you want to convert all object columns automatically and leave the numeric ones unchanged:
# example let's add numeric columns
df1['num1'] = 1
df2['num2'] = 2

out = pd.merge(df1.astype(dict.fromkeys(df1.select_dtypes('object'), 'category')),
               df2.astype(dict.fromkeys(df2.select_dtypes('object'), 'category')),
               on='col2', how='left')

out.dtypes
# col1    category
# col2      object
# num1       int64
# col3    category
# num2     float64
# dtype: object


Thanks for your response, this seems to kind of help and in fact reduce the memory usage. Unfortunately I oversimplified the problem, I have a lot more dataframes and columns than that and would love to find a more general solution like have col2.title or col2.description to access columns from df2 like in sql.

You can convert as many columns as you like to categorical. I don't understand how you can't generalize.

I'm thinking of non string elements. For instance I have columns with floats and converting them to float category removes the capacity to use inequalities (i think, from an error when using categories).

Then leave those as floats. Unlike strings, float won't be too expensive to store. If you want to convert part of the inputs to categorical, you can do so semi-automatically with: df1.astype(dict.fromkeys(df1.select_dtypes('object'), 'category'))

@CassayreValentin this is the right approach for doing this in pandas and should significantly help the problem with the data you've described. If your problem is that you fundamentally have too much data to store in memory after joining, either don't join, or use a library which doesn't store all the data in memory. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/scale.html
